# Unable to enter date using keyboard

Tags: angular, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

So I have this unique issue where I have a date field. I enter a date using the keyboard but when I come back to the field using tab, it won't let me enter the date again. I have to use backspace to remove the current date and then enter the date again.
Its Angular 6 code and I am using a single date picker.

The requirement is simple. once I enter the date using keyboard, I should be able to come back to the field and enter date again without using backspace. The entire date field gets highlighted when I use tab but I cannot enter any number till I remove the existing date.

[image: The attached image shows the actual issue]
code is not well formated but here it is for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) maybe you use this method, i try use keyboard it is work `material.angular.io`